# Excel VBA - Changing header names

Tags: vba, excel

In my script I am trying to change the header names of my table. When I run my code it skips over every column besides the last one and places only 1 name there and I am not sure why. Here is the code:

```
C = Sheets("Name").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Name").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$M$" & C), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Sheets("Name").ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

hdrs = Array("SUBSYSTEM", "Rack Assumbly", "Rack Number", "PRODUCT/COMPONENT ASSEMBLY NAME", "VERSION#", "OEM", "Part #", "U", "S", "SR", "CI", "TOTAL QUANTITY", "DESCRIPTION")
 For h = 0 To 12

    Sheets("Name").ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 13).Value = hdrs(h)

Next h
```

Where h and C are longs.

Comment: Trying changing .Cells(1, 13) to .Cells(1, h).

Comment: Had to edit a few things but that worked, thank you!